# 400 Response "Error reading object reference", caused by "$id" properties

Tags: javascript, rest, knockout.js, reference, http-status-code-400

I have a simple RESTful server with a client using Durandal. When I want to update an object and then send it back to the server, I get a 400 error complaining about `Error reading object reference` and referring to a `$id` property of objects.

Example of said object:

```
{
    $id="1", //What is this doing here? Is being put there when I got the object from server to update it
    name="John",
    pet={
        $id="1", //same as above
        name="Jim",
        type="dog"
}
```

I don't get the 400 when deleteing those props, but that's just ugly and unneeded code right?